# Pass parameters to dynamic controllers using ng-init

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope

I'm trying to get ng-init working with a custom dynamic controller directive.
The problem, I guess, is that ng-init can't recognize the controller which is concerned.

MainController

```
var vm = this;
vm.widgets = [{
  template: "path/to/file/OneWidget.html,
  controller: "OneWidgetController as vm"
}];
```

test.html

```
<div ng-repeat="widget in vm.widgets">
  <div layout="column" flex="100" 
  ng-include="widget.model.template"
  ms-dynamic-ctrl="widget.model.controller"
  ng-init="vm.init('whatever','hodor')"></div>
</div>
```

OneWidgetController

```
function OneWidgetController() {
    var vm = this;

    vm.init = function(param1, param2)
    {
        console.log(param1);
    };
}
```

ms-dynamic-ctrl

```
function msDynamicCtrl($controller)
{
    return {
        restrict : 'A',
        scope : true,
        link : function(scope, element, attrs) {

            var locals = {
                $scope : scope,
                $element : element,
                $attrs : attrs
            };

            element.data('$Controller', $controller(scope.$eval(attrs.msDynamicCtrl), locals));
        }
    };
}
```

All my controllers are stored in an array as string as following "OneWidgetController as vm" and this is working. I get the template loading fine with the controller associated to each view. Now i need to initialize each controller wwith some parameters.

Any thought on how to pass parameter to each controller with ng-init ?

UPDATE: Here is a plunkr trying to reproduce my problem.
https://plnkr.co/edit/FxVVMUzrcpPAG2n2UndM?p=preview

Comment: can you create a fiddle/plunker?

Comment: Try and use the ng-controller="vm as widget.model.controller" instead. And just declare the controller name in widget.model.controller model

Comment: I figured it out. I end up with creating an other directive to extract data for each items and save it in a service. Then, each controller load the right data by calling the service. Even if i have multiple items with the same unique controller, each get their proper data so I can build widgets with different references (api calls for example). Can update the plunkr if asked. Tx